# how to use wordpress authentication for user login in my android app

Tags: android, wordpress

I've build wordpress site and users can register and access their own data that is stored on different DB (WP using just as platform and users DB). now I like to add android application that retrieve some data from mySQL db (not WP DB). is it possible to use the wordpress authentication in order to login to the android app, I'll appreciate some reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what I´ll do is this:

1. Create a plugin in WP that give you a REST Webservice and by access to your   WP database you always knew when a user is login, logout, last access and get all the info you want or make any action on your WP site.
2. Then when you have the Webservices you can use it in your android app or other application. Here you have a full example how to call a REST Webservices in Android (http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/)

Here a HTTP REST API plugin for wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). And here the authentication guide (http://wp-api.org/guides/authentication.html)

Hope that can help you .

Answer (score 0):

What is required [I think]:
You have to first fetch the nonce generated from wp-login.php
Then you have to send the username and password WITH THE NONCE.
Then you have to capture 2 login cookies
Then additional requests must include the cookies and possible additional nonces.

As far as I can tell, there are no libraries for this. All current solutions call for using additional PHP to create various API login creds. This is foolish, since WordPress already has a built in authentication system [cookies].

So this is a partial answer... Correct me if I'm wrong... there are no JS libraries that can be used to login to WP through the default login system. Or are there?